# Treetop: parsing single node returns nil

Tags: ruby, parsing, grammar, treetop

I'm trying to get the basic of Treetop parsing. Here's a very simple bit of grammar so that I can say `ArithmeticParser.parse('2+2').value == 4`.

```
grammar Arithmetic
  rule additive
    first:number '+' second:number {
      def value
        first.value + second.value
      end
    }
  end

  rule number
    [1-9] [0-9]* {
      def value
        text_value.to_i
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Parsing `2+2` works correctly, returning a node. However, parsing `2` or `22` returns `nil`.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Though I'd normally delete the question, I wouldn't be surprised if someone else also fundamentally misunderstands Treetop, so I'll leave this here for reference.

Treetop doesn't just go through the rules, looking for which one applies. Instead, it starts at the first rule, and, if the first rule does not match, it must be *forced* to consider alternatives. Therefore, `/ number` must appear at the end of the `additive` rule.

```
grammar Arithmetic
  rule additive
    first:number '+' second:number {
      def value
        first.value + second.value
      end
    }
    / number
  end

  rule number
    [1-9] [0-9]* {
      def value
        text_value.to_i
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for a good question/answer, but I don't know if "number" should be considered "additive" perhaps you could define an "equation" rule that can return either the result of "additive" or a "number".